# Bolster as synonymous to caring?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Does below sentence makes sense?

`He bolsters me whenever I am in need of`

Here, I can't find any of dictionary meaning of bolster may fit here. Is this word usable in this context??

Comment: comment moved to answer...

Answer (score 4):

Here it means: He **supports** me whenever I am in need of (something).

From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bolster):

> to add to, support, or uphold

**For example:**

> They bolstered their morale by singing.

Comment: imo - right & wrong… you don't 'bolster someone' you bolster an attribute of theirs, their confidence/morale etc

Comment: @Tetsujin, yeah it seems attributes can be referred to this, because many of the sentence examples i have read from texts of computer science uses it like that way

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's useable in that way. You can bolster - support or encourage - an attribute, not the person.

> 'He bolsters my [confidence/morale/mood etc]…'

A bolster is also a type of pillow, btw, a support for sleeping, cylindrical rather than flat & rectangular, which I would guess is the original meaning; secondary would be its use as a support for a person's mental state.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bolster

Answer (score 1):

Longman DCE says in number 1: to bolster/to bolster up: to help someone to feel better and more positive.
http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bolster_1

Comment: But, most of tech sentences from many books use it in ways Tetsujin showed.